# Service run after Controller? returns undefined

Tags: json, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, angularjs-service

I'm loading json data into my app, but it always return undefined.
After many tests and changes I found out that the service runs after the controller or at least that's what I think it does.

Service

```
.factory('personService', function($http) {
    return {
        getPersons: function() {
            return $http.get('/persons.php');
        }
    }
})
```

Controller

```
.controller('personsCtrl', function($scope, personService) {
   var promise = personService.getPersons();
   promise.then(
      function(response) { 
        $scope.persons = response.data;
          console.log(response.data);//first
      },
      function(response) {
          console.log('failed loading');
      });

    console.log($scope.persons); //last
})
```

Console prints out the //last before the //first, which means it probably runs before it gets the data from the json file.

Console

```
undefined
[object object object]
```

Anyone has any idea what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is perfectly fine and there's no need to change it.

I wouldn't follow Vamsi's advice - sorry man - as it's always better to resolve the promise in the controller instead of resolving it immediately.

The reason for this is at some point you might want to chain it (`getPersons`) with other promises from other services:

```
personService.getPersons()
    .then(function(result){
        return service2.doSomething(result);
    })
    .then(function(result){
        return service3.doSomeOtherThing(result);
    })
    .then(function(result){
        return service4.doLastThing(result);
    })
    .catch(function (reason) {
        console.log(reason);
    })
    .finally(function(){
        // always executed.
    });
```

if you look at this bit of code you can see a typical promise chaining where each service uses the result from the previous promise and returns it to the following branch of the chain.

If something wrong happens you would be able to `catch` the error and move on.

Going back to your problem:

```
.controller('personsCtrl', function($scope, personService) {
   var promise = personService.getPersons();
   promise.then(
      function(response) { 
        $scope.persons = response.data;
          console.log(response.data);//first
      },
      function(response) {
          console.log('failed loading');
      });

    console.log($scope.persons); //last
});
```

promises can be delayed, especially when dealing with `$http` requests.

```
console.log($scope.persons); //last
```

is going to be called immediately cause the code is executed from the top to the bottom and the promise - again - might have some delay.

In a real case scenario you would define an empty array in your controller:

```
.controller('personsCtrl', function($scope, personService) {
     $scope.persons = [];
});
```

call a service and wait until the services returns the data:

```
.controller('personsCtrl', function($scope, personService) {
     $scope.persons = [];
     personService.getPersons()
          .then(function(result){
               $scope.persons = result.data;
          });
});
```

and populate your `$scope.persons` which would be bound to the UI and update the interface.

If you need to to some other things before you populate `$scope.persons` you can chain with another promise.

If you want to dig deeper into promises I would suggest to read this [article](http://pouchdb.com/2015/05/18/we-have-a-problem-with-promises.html) which is the best explanation I've found.

If you're interested to follow some really good guidance about controllers, promises and the way to build services [John Papa Style Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#resolving-promises-for-a-controller).

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. I'll defiantly check out the suggested article. thanks.

Comment: Glad I've helped Alice. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It is the way it works. Why are you concerned about "console.log($scope.persons); //last" you need to get the data in the controller and you are getting it. After the $http call, your $scope.person is getting updated, which will in turn updates your view.

How are you sure that "console.log($scope.persons);" is getting executed first than " console.log(response.data);"?

Try modifying your service as below.

```
.factory('personService', function($http) {

var getPersons= function() {

    return $http.get('/persons.php').then(function(result){
        return result.data;
    });
};
return { getPersons: getPersons};
});
```

Comment: Try modifying your code as I mentioned, it worked for me

Comment: Did you mean to type `function getPersons()`? I still don't get in the view.

Comment: No just replace your complete code for service, with the provided one

Comment: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (' I get this error on the ` getPersons: function() {` line

Comment: Can you post the complete error? You didn't get this error in the first place right?

Comment: `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'starter' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.` I get this. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Where did you use that module 'starter'? I couldn't see that in the code.

Comment: The factory is in the module starter `angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])` I think it breaks the code.

Comment: what is your app name? From the way I see, there is no mistake in this line "angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers'])", provided it is used in the appropriate place.

Comment: Starter. i meant your code `getPersons: function() {
        return $http.get('/persons.php');
        }` broke the code

Comment: I modified it a bit, use the updated one in your application